# How Slice text and add Read More button in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the "card-text" class it calls the text from the Json file but it is too long I would like to cut the text and add actions click on the "Read More" button but for only the clicked card to react, someone something ?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Modal
      v-if="showModal && GET_TRAILER.payload !== null"
      v-on:close="closeModal"
      :trailerAdress="GET_TRAILER.payload"
    ></Modal>
    <div>
      <div class="row" v-for="(obj,index) in GET_MOVIE" :key="index">
        <div class="card col-12 col-lg-3" style="width: 10rem;" v-for="movie in obj.payload" :key="movie.id">
          <img class="card-img-top" :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}`" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{movie.original_title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              {{movie.overview}}
            </p>

            <div class="buttonPosition">
              <button
                v-on:click="OpenTrailerModal(movie.id)"
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-success"
              >Watch Trailer</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button @click="MoreMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-warning moreBtn">Load More Movies</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
<template>
      <div class="container">
        <Modal
          v-if="showModal && GET_TRAILER.payload !== null"
          v-on:close="closeModal"
          :trailerAdress="GET_TRAILER.payload"
        ></Modal>
        <div>
          <div class="row" v-for="(obj,index) in GET_MOVIE" :key="index">
            <div class="card col-12 col-lg-3" style="width: 10rem;" v-for="movie in obj.payload" :key="movie.id">
              <img class="card-img-top" :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.poster_path}`" />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{movie.original_title}}</h5>

    ---------------------- Add this part ------------------------------

                <div class="card-text">
                 <p v-if="movie.readMore"> 
                   {{ movie.overview | limitDisplay }}
               <a v-if="movie.overview.length > 100" @click="toggleReadMore(obj.payload, movie.id, false)">Read More<a> 
                 </p>

                <p v-if="!movie.readMore">
                {{ movie.overview }}
                <a @click="toggleReadMore(true)">Read Less<a> 
                </p>
               </div>

    ---------------------------------------------------------------

                <div class="buttonPosition">
                  <button
                    v-on:click="OpenTrailerModal(movie.id)"
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                  >Watch Trailer</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button @click="MoreMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-warning moreBtn">Load More Movies</button>
      </div>
    </template>
```

In your script add this in your methods and filters :

```
methods: {

    toggleReadMore(payload, movie_id, value){

    payload = payload.map(function(item){
          if(item.id == movie_id){
              item['readMore'] = value;
              return item
          }
   });
}

},

filters : {

limitDisplay: function(value) {
  return value.substring(0, 100) + "...";
}

}
```

Comment: yes it works but for all cards :( , when readMore:true is in the data() of the component then the click switch works for all cards at once

Comment: You need to add a readMore property to your objects in your payload array initially as true before running this code.

Comment: YES YES, it's Alive THX, another small step